# how to enhance security on the files that they cant be access in the browser like audio mp3 and video flv

Tags: php, .htaccess, video, html5-audio, audio-streaming

i am developing music portal who will work on the subscrption bases. so user will be able to download and play audios files.
i am having number of security different issues in implementing this:
First: if i install IDM - it automatically download this audio/video in the software.
Second: any one accesses the file in the browser and plays it and so download it with the help of link.

How can i ensure high level security for this purpose. i am confused please.

I have used different codes to hide links but none of them works for me. i want to hide links of the path as well.

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function unloadJS(scriptName) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
  var js = document.getElementById(scriptName);
  js.parentNode.removeChild(js);
}

function unloadAllJS() {
  var jsArray = new Array();
  jsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  for (i = 0; i < jsArray.length; i++){
    if (jsArray[i].id){
      unloadJS(jsArray[i].id)
    }else{
      jsArray[i].parentNode.removeChild(jsArray[i]);
    }
  }       
}
</script>
```

but it is also not working as expecting and it is too showing all links and etc..

Comment: If you can't access files in the browser, you can't play them in the browser either. Security or usability - pick one.

Comment: we dont want to play the files in the browser. we have integrated number of best players etc. why hacker access payable files in the broswer? how can we let him do this and why??